# Moving a figure in console C++

Tags: c++

Im writing a program, which is supposed to print `"X'` made of ASCII chars in the console, change size and allow to move it with keys. I know how to print this X and change a size, but I'm totally stuck and i don't know how to move it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void Intro();
void Draw();

const int Esc = 27;

int main()
{
Intro();
Draw();

return 0;
}

void Intro()
{
std::cout << "Napisz program rysowania znakiem ponizszej figury:\n";
std::cout << "    *    * \n";
std::cout << "     *  *  \n";
std::cout << "      *    \n";
std::cout << "     *  *  \n";
std::cout << "    *    * \n";

std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Program powinien umozliwiac:\n"
    << " - Wybor znaku kodu ASII,\n"
    << " - Wczytanie poczatkowych rozmiarow figury,\n"
    << " - Zmiane wielkosci figury klawiszami '+' i '-',\n"
    << " - Przesuwanie figury w czterech kierunkach za pomoca kursorow,\n"
    << " - Ograniczenie przesuwania i rozmiarow figury do obszaru ekranu.\n";

_getch();

return;
}

void Draw()
{
int Size;
char AsciiChar;
char Tab[50][80];
int AsciiCharPosX = 0;
int AsciiCharPosY = 0;
char Key;

system("cls");

std::cout << "Enter the size: ";
std::cin >> Size;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter the ASCII char from the keyboard: ";
std::cin >> AsciiChar;
std::cout << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
    {
        Tab[i][j] = 'e';                                    // e - empty field
    }
}
Tab[AsciiCharPosX][AsciiCharPosY] = 'f';                    //f - filled

do
{
    system("cls");

    for (int Rows = 1; Rows <= Size; Rows++)
    {
        for (int Cols = 1; Cols <= Size; Cols++)
        {
            if (Rows == Cols || Cols == (Size + 1) - Rows)
            {
                Tab[Rows][Cols] = 'f';
                if (Tab[Rows][Cols] == 'f')
                {
                    std::cout << AsciiChar;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Tab[Rows][Cols] = 'e';
                if (Tab[Rows][Cols] == 'e')
                {
                    std::cout << " ";
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    Key = _getch();

    switch (Key)
    {
    case '+':
    {
        Size = Size + 2;
        break;
    }
    case '-':
    {
        Size = Size - 2;
        break;
    }
    case 's':
    {
        AsciiCharPosY++;
        break;
    }
    case 'w':
    {
        AsciiCharPosY--;
        break;
    }
    case 'a':
    {
        AsciiCharPosX--;
        break;
    }
    case 'd':
    {
        AsciiCharPosX++;
        break;
    }
    }
} while (Key != Esc);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Add spaces before each line or some empty lines above.

Comment: Please don't downvothe this question! It is a perfectly valid question that I know I struggled with as well when I was fresh.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

To move it you will need to follow one of 2 aproaches:

**Console control**

Write code that can send special characters that the console picks up to mean special things like *move cursor* or *change color* etc. The most common way is tu use a library for this, like [libncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Please note that this depends greatly on the console you are using, and sxo you need to find which code or library to use based on that.

**Faking it**

You can fake it by simply rewriting the whole screen-full of text while incorporating the changes you want and hope your victim (user) does not scroll upward to see what is going on.

In both cases, you will need to write out changes in steps (frames) and you will benefit by knowing about [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_basic_principles_of_animation).

Good luck!